# C - use the struct name as the parameter of function in strcut

Tags: c, struct, stack, declaration, typedef

I'm trying to implement stack in c. this is my code:

```
//header file
typedef struct
{
    ElementType Data[MaxSize];
    Position Top;
    
    int Push(SeqStack *L);
}SeqStack;
```

and this is what the compiler showed:

```
error: unknown type name 'SeqStack'
```

I'm not very familiar with c. What is the correct way to achieve such implementation?

Comment: Take the function outside of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

The name `SeqStack` is yet undefined in this line

```
int Push(SeqStack *L);
```

So the compiler issues an error.

Moreover you may not declare a function within a structure in C, You can declare a pointer to a function, Then when an object of the structure type will be defined you can initialize the pointer by some function.

You should write

```
typedef struct SeqStack
{
    ElementType Data[MaxSize];
    Position Top;
    
    int ( *Push )( struct SeqStack *L );
}SeqStack;
```

or

```
typedef struct SeqStack SeqStack;

struct SeqStack
{
    ElementType Data[MaxSize];
    Position Top;
    
    int ( *Push )( SeqStack *L );
};
```